# class to load multidimensional array from a file

Tags: php, arrays, oop, multidimensional-array, singleton

I want to create a singleton class that read multidimensional array from txt file and flatten the array retrieved in php.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
  class singleton {

        protected static $instance = null;         

        public static function getInstance() {
            if (!isset(static::$instance)) {
                static::$instance = new static;
            }
            return static::$instance;
        }
        public static function flattenArray($array) {

            $return = array();

            $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));

            foreach ($iterator as $value) {
                $return[] = $value;
            }
            return $return;
        }

        public static function loadFile($path) {

            $file_handle = fopen($path, "r");

            while (!feof($file_handle)) {

                $line = fgets($file_handle);

                $rawarray[] = $line;
            }

            $flattedarray = self::flattenArray($rawarray);

            fclose($file_handle);
            return $flattedarray;
        }
```

With the txt file containing:

```
array('a', 'b', array(array('c'), 'd'), 'e', array('f'), 'g')
```

I run the class with:

```
include 'singleton.php';

$singleton = singleton::getInstance();

$flattedarray = $singleton->loadFile("file.txt");

echo '<pre>';
print_r($flattedarray);
echo'</pre>';
```

I get as a result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => array('a', 'b', array(array('c'), 'd'), 'e', array('f'), 'g')
)
```

Which is the same array found in the txt file.

how can i do it without using eval ?

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why would you store an array like that in a txt file? You should store it as a json array or serialized.

Answer (score 0):

If your text file simple as showed then your could use this trick:

```
$string = "array('a', 'b', array(array('c'), 'd'), 'e', array('f'), 'g')";
$string = str_replace(['array(', ')', "'"], ['[',']', '"'], $string);
var_dump(json_decode($string));
```